# Why is it recommended to provide optional radix parameter to parseInt()?

Tags: javascript, parseint

I've always used the `parseInt()` function in Javascript without passing the radix parameter. As per the MDN documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), it's stated that not providing this parameter may result in unpredictable behaviour.

> Always specify this parameter to eliminate reader confusion and to
>   guarantee predictable behavior.

Could somebody clarify what does this unpredictable behavior mean with some code examples?

Comment: *"Different implementations produce different results when a radix is not specified, usually defaulting the value to 10."*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In older versions of the language, `parseInt()` would cause the function to obey the normal JavaScript numeric constant syntax rules, including the recognition of a leading zero to denote octal constants, and a leading 0x to denote hex constants. Thus, if your code didn't explicitly insist on base 10, stray (possibly user-supplied) numbers with leading zeros would be interpreted as base-8 values, and leading 0x as hex.

The base-8 behavior is gone since ES5.1 (I think; might have been earlier), but the base 16 behavior is still there. (Probably a leading 0x is a little more rare as an accidental prefix than a simple leading 0.)

My experience looking at code here on Stack Overflow is that `parseInt()` is overused anyway. It's *usually* cleaner to convert strings (often, strings taken from DOM element `.value` properties) to numbers with the unary `+` operator:

```
var count = +document.getElementById("count").value;
```

That won't necessarily give you an integer, of course. However, what it *will* do is notice that the input string has trailing non-numeric garbage. The `parseInt()` function will simply stop parsing a string like "123abc" and give you `123` as the numeric value. The leading `+` will however give you a `NaN`.

If you need integers, you can always use `Math.floor()` or `Math.round()`.

*edit* — a comment notes that ES2015 requires a leading `0o` or `0O` in "strict" mode for octal literals, but that doesn't apply to `parseInt()` which (in ES2015) only overrides the default radix for hex strings.

Comment: @Bathsheba I've never seen that mentioned, but of course I cannot say that nobody's whispered about it.

Comment: @Bathsheba In [ECMAScript 6/ES2015](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/), octals literals are in the format `0o` like binary: `0b` and hex: `0x`.

Comment: @AndrewLi that's true in "strict" mode; otherwise (in order not to break the Internet) there's "legacy" mode that continues to recognize just a leading `0`. But on the other hand I hadn't noted that about ES2015 (probably because I generally have no need for an octal literal).

Comment: + is shortcut for Number(x). this does not function the same as parseInt(x) with undefined, null, and empty string.

Comment: @TamusJRoyce that is true. Also, `parseInt("123hello world")` will return `123`, while the `+` operator would return `NaN`.  Also of course `parseInt()` only returns integers, with no fractional part.

Comment: @Pointy yep. I meant parseFloat(), not parseInt(). With +x being a shortcut for Number(x), Number(x) is easier to search how +x works.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason best known to themselves, the folk specifying the behaviour of this function set the radix to be a defaultable parameter but then decided to leave the default value up to the implementation! (Perhaps it would have been sensible to insist on a value of 10 but maybe that would have upset folk progamming in the 1970s who still consider octal literals to be useful.)

So for robust progamming, you need to supply the radix parameter yourself.

Comment: at least typescript or eslint gives this warning

Answer (score 0):

Without supplying the radix, `parseInt` tries to determine what the right radix is by the value you pass in, for example  if the value starts `0x` then it determines you must be passing in hex  values. Same applies with `0` (octal).

This becomes problematic when your input is zero-padded but no radix is supplied. Where the result will (possibly) not be as expected

```js
console.log(parseInt(015))
```

Comment: You're clearly at the opposite end of the expertise spectrum to me, but does the function *have to be* implemented in this way?

Comment: @Bathsheba I have no idea. If I was writing it I probably would have defaulted it to `10` as its clearly what 99% of users expect. We're base-10 creatures after all

Comment: @Bathsheba the current spec for the language still insists on recognizing a leading 0x or 0X as indicating a hex constant, but only when the radix is not explicitly passed as an argument.